# How to load a multi line text, edit it and then run as javascript like in eval()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, base64

**I need to follow these steps:**

1. Load an script text encoded base64 using Ajax (multiline included before encode).
2. Edit and Decode using atob()
3. Run it like in eval().

**But I have some issues:**

1. eval() doesn't works because It can't have line break.
2. I can't use "dataType=script" in Ajax because when dataType is script I just can't edit it before run.
3. I've tried to remove all comments and line breaks from loaded codes but it doesn't works. I got some errors and I things it's not the best way to do it.

**I've tried:**

```
var F = new Function(atob(data));
F();
```

But it doesn't works.

**The only way to works was:**

```
var script = "<script type='text/javascript'> " + atob(data) + " </script>";
$('body').append(script);
```

But I can't use that because my project will load a lot of requests and it isn't the ideal way since will add a lot of script tags in the DOM. In addition It is not synced with my main codes.

Comment: Why does it need to be base64 encoded? If this is an attempt to obscure it from users it really isn't very effective since they can simply read it after it is decoded

Comment: I can do some things in the string after encode and it will make the codes harder to recognize because of the amount of requests.